# In search of a set partitioning data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to perform a particular expensive computation for a set of objects and I'd like to find out if there are more efficient data structures or algorithms.

Suppose that we have a set of `N` (~1k) item that can be enumerated and so we can index them and represent them as integers. For each of these things I'd like to track a given state. But in general the number of unique states will be much smaller than `N`, at most `N/10`, but usually closer to `N/1000`.

To represent this map we can have:

1. An array of size N, with the state for each i'th item at i.
2. A tree data structure (I'm being specifically vague as I'm not certain of a potentially better tree/trie in this case), where each leaf has represent an item and a state.
3. A hash-table, similar to 3.
4. Have a list of pairs of bit vectors indicating a set of items and the state. So the total length of the list would be the number of unique states.
5. ...?

In the hot-path of my code, I need to take 2 such maps and merge them, such that each item's state is updated. If the cost of performing a merge is `k`, the running time given the array representation is `O(kN)`. In general the cost of `k` is on the order of a lookup, so memoization techniques do not help. This seems wasteful as I know that in general I only have `N/1000` unique values. Another consideration is the storage requirement of these maps. Storing `N` items is redundant and even enumerating all the items can be improved upon (#4 map).

Can I do better?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your only concern minimizing the time it takes to merge two maps? What about other operations (looking up the state of an object; looking up all objects for a given state; etc.)?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what your data or operations look like, but [the disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) sounds almost exactly like what you're describing.

Comment: @TedHopp, My main concern is the merge. I'll be merging 1000 times the number of lookups.

Comment: @Dukeling, I've often looked at the disjoin-set/ union find data structure, but it isn't obvious to me how to convert that logic into an efficient map form. Specifically, when comparing two set/value pairs, I would be able to apply merge two the elements that the two sets have in common, but I would then need to pass on their two (remaining in each) differences for further merging.

Comment: @LeonidR Your problem seems to be efficient merging of sets. Disjoint-set solves this problem by having all nodes in a set point to the same root node, which is all you need to modify in case of merging. If you want to map all nodes in a set to something, you can have the root node point to that or have a separate map containing only root nodes (merging sets of any size will involve only 1-2 updates to this map). If this doesn't make sense for your data, you may want to clarify by editing an example into your question.

Comment: I don't understand why the running time for the array representation is `O(kN)`. Suppose you have a constant-time function `f` that accepts the state of item `i` in each of two maps and returns the updated state for item `i`. Then just run through the two arrays using the same index `i`, compute `f(map1[i],  map2[i])`, and assign it as the new state of item `i`. That's an `O(N)` algorithm, not `O(kN)`. Or am I missing something about your problem?

Comment: @TedHopp I'm saying that `k` is the cost of the merge function `f`.